# % Wildcard not working with numbers?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following sqlite db:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `Field1`    TEXT
);
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('testing');
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('123');
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('87654');
COMMIT;
```

This select returns the correct result:

```
select * from table1 where Field1 like '%e%';
```

However this one returns nothing?

```
select * from table1 where Field1 like '%2%';
```

Even Stranger in DB Browser for SQLite:

```
select * from table1 where CAST(Field1 AS Text) LIKE '%2%'
```

Returns:

```
1 Rows returned from: select * from table1 where CAST(Field1 AS Text) LIKE '2%' (took %3ms)
```

Maybe a bug? Drops the first %

Comment: FWIW, I made a SQLFiddle and the issue cannot be reproduced there: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c8445/1

Comment: Interesting. I see it working there - I"ll do some more digging here. Not working with DB browser for SQLite.

Comment: Are all these SQL statements executed in DB Browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug in DB browser. I raised an issue and its now been fixed in the nightlies.